# What is the closest flyby to date?

Tags: probe, spacecraft, flyby, record

Cassini is to fly [within 50 km](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-34593944) of Enceladus.

What is the closest flyby a spacecraft has ever made? What object was targeted and when was it? Is 50 km a new record?

*(For the purposes of this question, an ultra-close orbit is also included, but lithobraking, landing, or any procedure that ultimately resulted in contact or was designed to, is not)*

Comment: 50 km is not a new record.Cassini already made a closest approach of 25 km in 2008.50 km is the closest to ever fly over the plumes.Check [this](http://www.dnaindia.com/scitech/report-cassini-will-dive-into-enceladus-erupting-plume-to-search-for-life-2139401)

Comment: IIRC, Apollo 10 came within about 15 nautical miles of the moon's surface.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Apollo 10 got below 16 KM (not miles) of the Moon's surface, that's less than **10 miles**.

Comment: @dotancohen ah, right, looks like I misremembered that. In any case, it's certainly the closest *manned* flyby.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JAXA's [Hayabusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa) came to within **44 meters** of [25143 Itokawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25143_Itokawa), which, in an unfortunate sequence of events, lead to its lander [MINERVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa#MINERVA_mini-lander) to miss the target:

> MINERVA was deployed on 12 November 2005. The lander release command
>   was sent from Earth, but before the command could arrive, Hayabusa's
>   altimeter measured its distance from Itokawa to be 44 m (144 ft) and
>   thus started an automatic altitude keeping sequence. As a result, when
>   the MINERVA release command arrived, MINERVA was released while the
>   probe was ascending and at a higher altitude than intended, so that it
>   escaped Itokawa's gravitational pull and tumbled into space.

It is possible that MINERVA itself came closer to Itokawa than 44 meters, but it was an unpowered mini lander, so that probably doesn't count:

[image: Hayabusa's MINERVA lander missing the asteroid 25143 Itokawa]

<sup>MINERVA lander (in yellow circle) missing the asteroid 25143 Itokawa as seen by Hayabusa probe. Image: [JAXA](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.isas.jaxa.jp%2Fj%2Fsnews%2F2005%2F1113.shtml&edit-text=&act=url)</sup>

---

Perhaps also interesting (tho it doesn't fit requirements of your question), a week later and as a result of a separate set of approach maneuvers, Hayabusa also [landed on the asteroid, collected samples, and then took off again](http://www.isas.jaxa.jp/e/snews/2005/1124_hayabusa.shtml). Next probe to perform a similar feat of briefly touching an asteroid to collect samples will be NASA's [OSIRIS-REx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSIRIS-REx#Sample_acquisition) at [101955 Bennu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101955_Bennu).

Answer (score 10):

Chinese [Chang'e 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4179_Toutatis) flew 3.2 km from the asteroid 4179 Toutatis (size: 4.7×2.4×1.9 km) in 2012 after having ended its primary Lunar mission. Maybe a record for intentional flyby's?

[image]

[image]

[Here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets_and_comets_visited_by_spacecraft) of the 21 asteroids and comets and minor planets visited by spacecrafts, with closest approach altitude. One way to define it is in number of object radii, and then Dawn wins at Ceres according to that table (but many Earth, Moon, Mercury, Venus and Mars orbiters beat that).

Answer (score 5):

The closest I know of is [Rosetta](http://www.universetoday.com/118777/rosetta-to-snuggle-up-to-comet-67p-for-closest-encounter-yet/), which orbited 67P at altitudes down to 6 km.

Comment: I didn't realize they dared take it so low to an active comet. I thought Cassini's 50 km from Enceladus in 2008 and Mars Express 45 km from Phobos in 2013 would be near records.

Comment: 6 km orbits were done early in the mission when the comet was less active. At the moment (close to perihelion) they're several hundred km away.

Comment: @LocalFluff That orbit turned out to be too close and [Rosetta's star tracker started confusing comet's debris for stars](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2015/04/01/rosetta-status-report-close-flyby-navigation-issues/), so they increased its orbit again. But I believe they plan to eventually "soft crash" / "hard land" the probe into the comet (I didn't follow up if it was approved, but it was proposed by Matt Taylor).

Comment: Rosetta's orbit is now 0 km ;-)